# Jasper Reports - Erro pegando valor do bean

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, jasper

estou procurando há 3 dias já e não consigo solucionar esse problema.
Vamos a explicação:
Estou criando um relatório no jaspersoft studio e fazendo o link com meu banco de dados, no preview do meu relatório(dentro do software jaspersoft) está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. Como pode ser visto nas imagens a seguir:
[image: Meu relatório jrxml]

[image: Como ele fica no preview]

Tenho apenas 3 fields no meu relatório: nome, medida e bairro.

Dentro do meu software, quando chamo o relatório ele da dois erros diferentes, que não consigo saber o que fazer.

Segue meus códigos fontes para melhor visualização:

**RelatorioUtils - Classe que vai gerar o relatorio**

```
public static void executarRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nomeRelatorio, JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados) throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    //pegar caminho do relatorio jasper
    InputStream reportStream = context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(caminhoRelatorio);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    try {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutput = null;
        try {
            servletOutput = response.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (parametros == null) {
            parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutput, parametros, fonteDados);

        try {
            servletOutput.flush();
            servletOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        context.getResponseComplete();
    }
}
```

**Meu Managed Bean**

```
public void emitir() {
    relatorios = dao.listarTodos();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(relatorios); // aqui está vindo completo meu JRbeanCollection está trazendo todos os dados que preciso
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context.getExternalContext().getContext();


    try {
        RelatorioUtil.executarRelatorio("/relatorios/RelatorioMedidaCautelar.jasper", null, "Relatorio", fonteDados);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MBRelatorio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Esse é o erro que ele gera

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:109) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1614) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:150) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:892) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:649) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:437) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:858) at br.com.agilles.medidas.utils.RelatorioUtil.executarRelatorio(RelatorioUtil.java:57) at br.com.agilles.medidas.beans.MBRelatorio.emitir(MBRelatorio.java:58) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class br.com.agilles.medidas.models.Relatorio' at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1277) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111) ... 57 more

Importante dizer:
Meu JRBeanCollectionDataSource esta vindo completamente preenchido
com todos os dados corretos: nome, medida e bairro.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class br.com.agilles.medidas.models.Relatorio'`
Parece que aqui, ele está tentando encontrar uma variavel com declaração de field vazio, e não encontra nenhuma variavel declarada como "". Eu nunca trabalhei muito com JR, mas tenta ver se o seu fonteDados contém os fields que precisa popular, com os nomes corretos.

Comment: É mesmo, parece que ele tenta acessar por reflexão dentro da classe Relatório um campo sem nome.

Comment: meu fonte de dados esta vindo com os mesmos campos do relatorio. Ele vem com um array de tamanho 3 que esta vindo do banco. Cada objeto esta populado com o campo nome, medida e bairro.

Comment: Entendo, @Jilles. Por favor, verifica se não há nenhum valor errado dentro do arquivo `.jrxml`, e também, se possível, edite a pergunte e coloque a classe `Relatorio`.

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi, o problema era no JRXML mesmo, quando ele pega os fields através da query, no xml ele gera um tal de field description, e nesse field description vem em branco, e é nele que preciso colocar os nomes iguais meus atributos da minha aplicação.